# Webpack warns that the "combined asset size" is exceeding 244 KiB after code splitting

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

After running the Webpack Bundle Analyzer plugin, it was clear that react-dom was the largest dependency that was effecting the size of my bundle.

I split out react and react-dom into it's own chunk by adding the following:

```html
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        reactVendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom|react-router-dom)[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor-react',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

The chunk was created and my main bundle shrunk down in size, however, Webpack is now giving me a similar warning where "The following entrypoint(s) **combined** asset size exceeds the recommended size".

Results after splitting out react-dom:

`asset main.bundle.js 164 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset`

`asset vendor-react.bundle.js 134 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: vendor-react) (id hint: reactVendor) 1 related asset`

`Warning: Entrypoint main [big] 298 KiB = vendor-react.bundle.js 134 KiB main.bundle.js 164 KiB`

Any recommendations on what I am doing wrong, or best practices on how this should be handled?

Comment: Not a good idea to touch react and react-dom, as without either your website will fail. Honestly, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Your users won't see a difference if your chunks are 164kiB vs 100kiB. If you want your website to hit 100s on all metrics rewrite it in another framework (Svelte comes to mind), or at least use SSR frameworks like Next or Remix.

Comment: Yeah I am not extremely worried about it, but more I just feel like I am missing something or doing something incorrectly. It's not clear to me why Webpack recommends you code split, but then it still warns about the combined bundle size being a performance issue.